# AttributeError: 'Television' object has no attribute 'volume'

Tags: python

so here is my code

```
# Television Remote

class Television(object):

    def ___init___(self, channel = 15, volume = 20):
        self.channel = channel
        self.volume = volume

    def channell(self, value):
        if value > 20:
            print("Max channel is 20")
            self.channel = 20
            return self.channel

        else:
            self.channel = value
            return self.channel
            print("Channel is now ", self.channel)



    def volume_increase(self):
        if self.volume != 100:
            self.volume += 1
            return self.volume
        else:
            return self.volume



    def volume_decrease(self):
        if self.volume != 0:
            self.volume -= 1
            return self.volume

        else:  
            return self.volume


    def channel_up(self):
        if self.channel == 20: # 20 is the maximum channel allowed
            self.channel = 1   # so it returns to 1
            return self.channel


        else:
            self.channel += 1
            return self.channel


    def channel_down(self):
        if self.channel == 1:
            self.channel = 20
            return self.channel


        else:
            self.channel -= 1
            return self.channel




c = Television()
choice = None
while choice != "0":
    print(
        """
        Television Remote

        0 - Quit
        1 - Input Channel
        2 - Change Channel Up
        3 - Change Channel Down
        4 - Volume Up
        5 - Volume Down
        """)

    choice = input("Choice: ")
    if choice == "0":
        print("Good Bye")
    elif choice == "1":
        value = int(input("What channel? "))
        c.channell(value)
        print("Turning to Channel ", c.channel)
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Channel ", c.channel_up())
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Channel ", c.channel_down())
    elif choice == "4":
        print(c.volume_increase())
    elif choice == "5":
        print(c.volume_decrease())
    else:
        print("Choice ", choice, " isn't a valid choice.")



input("Press enter to exit.")
```

when I chose 2 - 4, it would output :

> (AttributeError: 'Television' object has no attribute 'volume',)

I don't understand why but if I only write this code

```
class Television(object):
    def __init__(self, channel = 15, volume = 20):
        self.channel = channel
        self.volume = volume

    def volume_increase(self):
        if self.volume != 100:            
            self.volume += 1
            return self.volume
        else:
            return self.volume

c = Television()
choice = None
while choice != "0":
    print(
        """
        Television Remote

        0 - Quit
        1 - Input Channel
        2 - Change Channel Up
        3 - Change Channel Down
        4 - Volume Up
        5 - Volume Down
        """)

    choice = input("Choice: ")
    if choice == "0":
        print("Good Bye")
    elif choice == "1":
        value = int(input("What channel? "))
        c.channell(value)
        print("Turning to Channel ", c.channel)
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Channel ", c.channel_up())
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Channel ", c.channel_down())
    elif choice == "4":
        print(c.volume_increase())
    elif choice == "5":
        print(c.volume_decrease())
    else:
        print("Choice ", choice, " isn't a valid choice.")
```

and only choose "4", the code works. Can someone explain it to me why the first code won't work and the 2nd code works?

If you don't understand my question, I will explain it to you in a more detailed way I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your `___init___()` function with an extra underscore on both side, so it is not the `__init__()` (initialization method, but just another instance method) .

Define the `__init__()` function with just two underscore , not three -

```
# Television Remote

class Television(object):

    def __init__(self, channel = 15, volume = 20):
        self.channel = channel
        self.volume = volume
```

Comment: OOps, It is now running properly. Thanks! say if you don't mind. May I ask another question, as a beginner, where do you learn python?

Comment: There are lots of very good tutorials out there, one can be - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ (Python's own tutorial).